# How do I make a privileged port non-privileged in Redhat 5?

Tags: redhat, port

So I have a RedHat 5 box that I'm wanting to run an application that I wrote that implements SLP.  SLP uses port 427 for answering service queries.  My understanding is that ports below 1024 are "privileged" and thus cannot be bound to by anyone that's not root.  I cannot run this application as root as it is launched via tomcat.

One creative solution I really like was simply writing an iptables rule to route the privileged port to a non-privileged.  In my proof of concept tests, this works wonderfully.  Unfortunately, it would be greatly (and understandably) desired by the powers if my application did not require screwing around with iptables upon installation.

So I heard a rumor and cannot find anything to verify this that there was some sort of command or parameter that could be set to make any port I want be non-privileged.  Is this true?  If so, how is this done?  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So I saw this post on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l  It looks like he used something called capabilities.  The problem with this is it seems to require kernel 2.6.24+, but I only have access to kernel 2.6.18.  Is there a way to set capabilities on a 2.6.18 box?

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially asking the same thing as this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544713/starting-tomcat-on-port-80-on-centos-release-5-5-final

So, use jsvc.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but am I asking the same question?  My understanding is that jsvc will start tomcat as root and then drop down to a normal user.  Let's assume that I start Tomcat this way.  I still couldn't open up port 427, could I?  By the time Tomcat starts my war, I'd be a regular user, wouldn't I?

Comment: I haven't used jsvc, but if it can bind to port 80 and then drop privs, you can certainly bind to port 427 and drop privs.  That's actually the "standard" way of dealing with privileged ports running on a non-root process: you bind to the low port as root and then drop privileges (or you have a master process running as root, which will spawn child workers that do the actual work).

Comment: An alternative would be to do the "standard" thing with serving from Tomcat, which is to use a proxy like Apache (and have it handle static content, etc).  I'm not sure about the case of your application, but Apache can certainly bind to 427 and proxy over to your Tomcat running on a high port.

Comment: I'm not for sure, but the proxying may not work since I'm trying to listen for and send out multicast UDP datagrams, not TCP HTTP packets.  But it may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

A bandaid approach would be to listen non a non-privileged port, then redirect with xinetd from the privileged port.

```
$ grep bandaid /etc/services
bandaid         190/tcp                       # bandaid

$ cat /etc/xinetd.d/bandaid
service bandaid
{
    disable = no
    bind = 10.0.0.45
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    user = nobody
    redirect = localhost 8888
}
```

This is an awful idea IMO, but sometimes you don't have any other options.

Comment: I'm intrigued, Jodie.  Why is this an awful idea?

Comment: It's that forwarding the TCP connection is a bandaid. In a better solution you would run the app itself as a xinetd service on that port. [xinetd unprivileged port question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35104/is-xinetd-still-the-best-method-to-let-non-root-daemons-listen-on-privileged-por)

Comment: After doing some research, it appears that xinetd does not support redirecting a UDP port. :(  SLP uses broadcast datagrams.  So I cannot use the xinetd solution.  That being said, this looks like it would be great solution for other situations.

Comment: Could you just run the software as a xinetd service?

Comment: No.  It's part of a java web archive (war) as a ServletContextListener.  When Tomcat starts the war, the listener then kicks off and binds to the port.  My gut tells me that my boss would not want to tear this process away from the war.

Comment: Note that you don't have to add the entry to /etc/services if you specify "type = UNLISTED" and "port = xxx". This lets you keep the configuration self-contained within /etc/xinetd.d/bandaid instead of changing the out-of-the-box /etc/services.